# Hide/show DrawerItems in some conditions flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

i want to hide some options on my drawer if the user is not loggedIn

here's the DrawerItem widget :

```
Widget drawerItem(item) {

if (item['show'] == false) return const SizedBox();

final isListing = Config().isListingType;

switch (item['type']) {

  case 'pointEnd':
    {
      return ListTile(
          leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.bag_badge_plus,
              size: 25),
          title: Text(S.of(context).myPoints),
          onTap : () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => UserPoint(),
            ),
      )
);
```

i want to show the Endpoint only if the user is loggedIn

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a widgets collection and add the corresponding items to it based on your needs. Like

```
Widget _buildDrawer() {
  List<ListTile> listTile = [
    ListTile(),
    ListTile(),
  ];

  /// Check the condition here to add more list tiles to the listTile collection
  /// If the user is logged In.
  if (hasUserLoggedIn) {
    listTile.add(ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.bag_badge_plus, size: 25),
        title: Text(s.of(context).myPoints),
        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => UserPoint(),
              ),
            )));
  }

  return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: listTile,
    ),
  );
}
``
```